# как добавить все последующие элемента списка в новый список?

Tags: python, list

```
a = ['on', 'the', 'other', 'hand', 'nowadays', 'there', 'are', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'jobs', 'which', 'do', 'not', 'require', 'a', 'university', 'degree']

b = "there"

new_list = ['there', 'are', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'jobs', 'which', 'do', 'not', 'require', 'a', 'university', 'degree']
```

Comment: `new_list = a[a.index('there'):]`

Comment: Исправьте свой вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, какой список куда вы хотите добавить. и проложите свой код - что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написали в комменте к вашему вопросу, существует `index`, возвращающий позицию первого совпадения(в списке элементы `'there'` могут повторяться). Если совпадения не найдено, возникает `ValueError`.
Далее воспользуемся "срезом", т.е. `[x:]` - с позиции `x` и до конца списка, т.к параметр после `:` пропущен.
В итоге получаем:

```
new_list = a[a.index(b):]
```

Обращаю внимание, что срез возвращает новый список, т.е. манипуляции над `a` и `new_list` не влияют друг на друга. Такого эффекта можно добиться еще вот таким образом:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
independent_list = list(my_list)
```

Так мы кладем в переменную `independent_list` - копию, а не ссылку.